# Calendar for Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, calendar

I'm new to AngularJS and Ionic Framework, My present project now is to develop and integrate calendar event application for a mobile app. I already have the UI and only the integration is my problem to achieve this. Do you have guys any links or tutorial on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple options:

make a calendar ui
1: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

use native device calendar
2:https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/02/using-native-device-calendar-ionic-framework/

do the same with ng-cordova
3: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/calendar/

Comment: thank you for giving me this links, I'm working on with this. Trying to fix the installation. As of now the calendar appear to my device and I am trying to study the whole codes of this.http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ helps me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I always download js script files and put them in the www js folder so that I don't have to rely on a network connection for my app to run

Comment: Dragging inside the calendar was disabled when I run it to my device? Is there another way to make them same as when run in the browser?

Comment: Dragging inside the calendar was disabled when I run it to my device? Is there another way to make them same as when run in the browser?